# finding album title of longest album

Tags: sqlite

if i do the following in SQLite, i can get albums and the sum lengths of all their tracks, or length of the album. the Album table has id (primary key) and title. Tracks table has id (primary key), name, length, rating, count, album_id, genre_id.

```
SELECT title, SUM(length)
FROM Album JOIN Tracks ON Tracks.id=Album.id
GROUP BY album_id
```

How can I print ONLY the album title of longest album?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       select a.title, sum(t.length) 
       from album a, track t 
       where a.id = t.album_id group by a.title 
       order by sum(t.length) desc limit 1;
```